# what driver might work with asus strix-gtx960-dc2oc-2gd5 in ubuntu 14.04.1?

Tags: graphics

I have a new machine that has an Asus strix-gtx960-dc2oc-2gd5 graphics card. I have just installed Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS. Kernel is 3.16.0-44-generic I can't set the display resolution high enough or use dual display with the default driver. Does anyone know what driver might be best? Proprietary is fine.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

That's an nVidia card.  The open source driver nouveau should have been installed already, but many users opt for the proprietary driver instead.  More info here:

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BinaryDriverHowto/Nvidia